# Add columns values in pyspark for the same customerID

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DF one is full load and other is incremental, I want to add data for the customer_ID which are same in both the data_frames. So that my final output is that the customer_ID is same but the value is updated. I want to do it in data frame, I have another approach which is upsert but for that few staging tables have to be made which I want to avoid , how can I do add the data to the main table

Full Table

| customer_ID | amount |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1234 | 20 |
| ABC1235 | 10 |
| ABC2222 | 20 |
| ABC1345 | 10 |
| ABC4444 | 5 |
| ABC5555 | 9 |

incremental_load

| customer_ID | amount |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1234 | 5 |
| ABC1235 | 5 |
| ABC2222 | 7 |
| ABC1345 | 20 |
| ABC9999 | 15 |

Desired_output

| customer_ID | amount |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1234 | 25 |
| ABC1235 | 15 |
| ABC2222 | 27 |
| ABC1345 | 30 |
| ABC4444 | 5 |
| ABC5555 | 9 |
| ABC9999 | 15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can union both dataframes and then sum all entries for the same customer:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dfFull= ...
dfInc=...

dfResult=dfFull.union(dfInc).groupBy('customer_ID').agg(F.sum('amount').alias('amount'))
```

Comment: I am not able to get the correct results of the data on bigger dataset . how can I fix it?

Comment: @bigDataArtist what kind of error do you see?

Comment: I was able to solve it. Thanks